# How can i get request headers in chrome dev tools console?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

is there any way to get the request headers in chrome like you would in the 'Network' tab, but only using the console?

I tried something with 'performance.getEntries()' but it didn't lead me nowhere and I don't really know of any other methods I should try

Comment: There's no such method. Try looking for a chrome extension that does something like that.